# Extract broken JSON from response

Tags: json, python-3.x, python-requests

I am using `requests` in python3 to send post request to yahoo login website, in Burpsuite I got the following response:

```
HTTP/1.0 200 OK
X-Frame-Options: DENY
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
Age: 0
Pragma: no-cache
Expires: 0
Referrer-Policy: origin-when-cross-origin
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate
set-cookie: AS=v=1&s=8ZJenFRo&d=A611b9f16|50....OXCxVzImJQI-~A; path=/; domain=login.yahoo.com; secure; HttpOnly
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 149
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Date: Tue, 17 Aug 2021 11:20:50 GMT
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=15552000
Server: ATS

{"location":"/account/challenge/recaptcha?done=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.yahoo.com%2F&sessionIndex=QQ--&acrumb=8ZJenFRo&display=login&authMechanism=primary"}
```

The goal is to get this line in python

```
{"location":"/account/challenge/recaptcha?done=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.yahoo.com%2F&sessionIndex=QQ--&acrumb=8ZJenFRo&display=login&authMechanism=primary"}
```

I wrote a simple script to do the post request but it crashes when `response.json()` is called

```
import requests
from user_agent import generate_user_agent

def check_yahoo(email):
  yahoo_url = "https://login.yahoo.com"
  data= {"username":f"{email}"}
  heads = {"User-Agent":f"{generate_user_agent()}"}
  response = requests.post(yahoo_url , params=data , headers=heads)
  print (response.json())
  return 

#driver code 
check_yahoo("some.one@yahoo.com")
```

How do you extract json data if it was broken

Error

```
  File "/home/kali/Desktop/yah00/yah00.py", line 49, in <module>
    check_yahoo(item)
  File "/home/kali/Desktop/yah00/yah00.py", line 37, in check_yahoo
    print (response.json())
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/models.py", line 900, in json
    return complexjson.loads(self.text, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/simplejson/__init__.py", line 525, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/simplejson/decoder.py", line 370, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/simplejson/decoder.py", line 400, in raw_decode
    return self.scan_once(s, idx=_w(s, idx).end())
simplejson.errors.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

The json looks ok so it might be that the empty line is throwing it off. What is the content of `response.text`? If that includes the empty line, something like

```
json.loads(response.text.strip())
```

might be enough.

Comment: got the same error, why did you use `response.text`

Comment: `response.text` is the raw text content of the response. The `json` method is a convenience method that parses the text into a json object. The idea of using `text` was to see if there was additional whitespace causing the parsing to fail. If you print `response.text` directly, what do you get?

Comment: I get the page source code same found when in the browser

Comment: Then it looks like you need a different URL. I'm not familiar with BurpSuite, are you sure you're making the same request?

Comment: pretty sure I did and even got the same result with postman

Comment: Without knowing what additional headers are being added by postman/burpsuite, I'm not sure anyone can debug this, Python is behaving as expected.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a try/except to debug your error, like:

```
    def some_function(data):
       try:
          *enter your success code*
       except:
          *enter in error statement*
```

see more information in https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html

Comment: I know how to handle errors I am interested in the info inside that json data